# Good example of gprof, for iOS project

Tags: ios, debugging, xcode, profiling

The GNU profiler `gprof`, can be used to profile any application right on the device, allowing real world profiling.

As Xcode 4.5 based on LLVM plus it has GNU Debugger, Profiler, and others.

I need a better example, implementation example, for iOS projects.

Comment: [*You sound like a fan of `gprof`.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1779343/23771)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize the followings

- http://docs.freebsd.org/44doc/psd/18.gprof/paper.pdf
- http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/about/